# Puzzled about why I can't add strings together

Tags: python, accumulator

I am trying to write a program that gets user information and adds it to a list and then I want to total how many user inputs there were, but I can't do it. I have tried running an accumulator, but I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.

```
def main():
    #total = 0

    cel_list = []

    another_celeb = 'y'

    while another_celeb == 'y' or another_celeb == 'Y':

        celeb = input('Enter a favorite celebrity: ')

        cel_list.append(celeb)

        print('Would you like to add another celebrity?')

        another_celeb = input('y = yes, done = no: ')


        print()
    print('These are the celebrities you added to the list:')
    for celeb in cel_list:
        print(celeb)
        #total = total + celeb
        #print('The number of celebrities you have added is:', total)



main()
```

Here is the output as desired without the accumulator, but I still need to add the input together. I have commented out the accumulator.

```
Enter a favorite celebrity: Brad Pitt
Would you like to add another celebrity?
y = yes, done = no: y

Enter a favorite celebrity: Jennifer Anniston
Would you like to add another celebrity?
y = yes, done = no: done

These are the celebrities you added to the list:
Brad Pitt
Jennifer Anniston
>>>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a dynamically typed language. So, when you type `total = 0`, the variable total becomes an integer i.e Python assigns a type to a variable depending on the value it contains.

You can check the type of any variable in python using `type(variable_name)`.

**len(object)** returns **integer** value.

```
for celeb in cel_list:
    print(celeb)

#end of for loop
total = 0
total = total + len(cel_list) # int + int
print('The number of celebrities you have added is:', total)
```

Comment: the user input then, The number of celebrities you have added is:', then iterates again and again. Input or output by this time and then, The number of celebrities you have added is: like so

Comment: Enter a favorite celebrity: Jen Anniston
Would you like to add another celebrity?
y = yes, done = no: y

Enter a favorite celebrity: Brad Pitt
Would you like to add another celebrity?
y = yes, done = no: y

Enter a favorite celebrity: Jim Brown
Would you like to add another celebrity?
y = yes, done = no: done

These are the celebrities you added to the list:
Jen Anniston
The number of celebrities you have added is: 3
Brad Pitt
The number of celebrities you have added is: 3
Jim Brown
The number of celebrities you have added is: 3

Comment: @user3818550 - That's because in the code posted in your question, you have the print statement inside the for loop. In the answer, I have the print statement outside for loop.

Comment: @user3818550 - You can end a for loop by decreasing the indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Total is an integer ( declared earlier on as )

```
    total = 0
```

As the error code suggest, you are trying to join an integer with a string. That is not allowed. To get pass this error, you may :

```
    ## convert total from int to str
    output = str(total) + celeb
    print(" the number of celebrities you have added is', output)
```

or even better you can try using string formatting

```
    ##output = str(total) + celeb
    ## using string formatting instead
    print(" the number of celebrities you have added is %s %s', %  (total, celeb))
```

I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of entries in a Python list by using the [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function. So, just use the following:

```
print('These are the celebrities you added to the list:')
for celeb in cel_list:
    print(celeb)
total = len(cel_list)
print('The number of celebrities you have added is: ' + str(total))
```

Note the decreased indentation of the last two lines - you only need to run them once, after you've finished printing out the celeb's names.